# javascript sandbox a module to prevent reference to Window

Tags: javascript, sandbox

I trying to create a sandbox module that can take a object and prevent that object's code reference to window.

here is how it work in concept.

```
var sand = function(window) {
var module = {
    say: function() {
        console.log(window.location);
    }   
};
return module;
}
sand({}).say(); // window.location is undefine
```

This doesn't work if the object is pass-in

```
var $sand = (function(){
return function(obj, context) {
    return (function(obj, window) {
        window.module = {};
        // doesn't work even copy object
        for (p in obj) {
            window.module[p] = obj[p];
        }
        console.log(window.location); // undefine
        return window.module;
    }(obj, context));
};
}());

var module = {
say: function() {
    console.log(window.location);
}
};

$sand(module, {}).say(); // still reference to window.location
```

How can i make this pattern work?

Comment: I am a little unclear, do you mean you want:`var sand = function(window) { var module = { say: function() { alert(typeof window.location); } }; return module; } sand(undefined).say();` which would make "window" not a defined object inside?  In other words, this returns "true" `alert(null ==window);`

Comment: Bad news: FORGET IT. Preventing access to the global object is *impossible* - "shadowing" the name is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have a variable shadowing `window` in the scope of your function, the function will be able to access `window`. Even if you had a variable called `window`, the code will still be able to access the properties by simply omitting `window.`.

```
(function(window) {
    console.log(window.location); //undefined
    console.log(location); //this will still work
})({ });
```

In other words, sandboxing JavaScript in a browser environment is not possible  like this.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the only reason window is `undefined` is because you are passing in an empty object and calling the argument `window`, so it is hiding the real `window`.

Also, you can always get access to the window object by hoisting the `this` variable inside a closure, like so:

```
console.log ( ( function () { return this; } )() );
```

So even if you somehow manage to block `window`, it's trivial to get it back again.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the function outside your sandbox, the context will be the current one, and you can't really do otherwise.

If you really want to do some sandboxing, then you should use iframes to achieve that. Take a look at https://github.com/substack/vm-browserify it is a browser version of the `vm` module of node, you should be able to extract some good pieces of work, and avoiding `eval` which is not really clean for what you want to do.

Comment: thanks for all the answer. I found Dean Edward had done this since 2006... http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/11/sandbox/